# MonoDevelop does not show a console window for a Console Application

Tags: linux, monodevelop

I created a new Console Project in MonoDevelop and when I try to execute it (e.g. the default Hello World program) no console window appears, but MonoDevelop says it is already running.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable output on an external console in order for a console window to appear.

- Go to `Project > %ProjectName% Options > Run > General`
- OR: on the left Solution View, click the gear icon of your project and go to `Options > Run > General`
- Check "Run on external console"

The console window should now appear in your system's default console.